# Выбор существующих значений MySQL

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Друзья подскажите! 
Есть БД в ней есть таблица с полями котактов!
Пример
VK
Steam
Youtube
В ячейках записываються IDшники, так вот как их вывести через PHP, только существующие, например если нет steam то что бы его не выводило! 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `steam` != ''");
```

если я правильно понял то это то, что нужно.

Или

```
if (!empty($q['steam'])) {
код
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Выбираешь все ID-шники из базы. Дальше средствами php проверяй если значение не пустое то ничего не выводить. Или если тебе нужно сделать список подключённых сервисов, то те которые не подключены выводить ч/б иконку.

Comment: А подскажи как проверить на пустое значение - это мне нужно)

Comment: if($r['ID_Vkontakte'] != ''){

}

Comment: а в каком формате вся эта инфа хранится в таблице? отдельными строками или в одной строке в разных полях?